# make a hyperlink also submit some form information

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, jinja2

There are a good number of questions on this but none describing quite my situation.

For ease of use and to help out Google's search indexing of my site I would like to change a section of radio buttons to hyperlinks that submit a form as well as change the page.

My tentative code is like this but isn't quite going through.  Will this submit  a form to the server?  By the way I am using google app engine with python as a server language and jinja2 for templating.

```
<ul>
  <form name="myForm">
    <li><a href="/air/skydiving"><input type="hidden1" name="foo1" value="bar1">Skydiving</a></li>

    <li><a href="/air/paragliding"><input type="hidden" name="foo2" value="bar2">Paragliding</a></li>

    <li><a href="/air/hanggliding"><input type="hidden" name="foo3" value="bar3">hang gliding</a></li>

    <li><a href="/air/basejumping"><input type="hidden" name="foo4" value="bar4">base jumping</a></li>
   </form>
</ul>
```

Update:  So I realized this was a bad question and I was forgetting one of the first things I learned about HTML.  I needed to use the GET request to send some parameters to my python server script that allow it to take care of the rest.  Here is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/air?s=1">Skydiving</a></li>
    <li><a href="/air?s=2">Paragliding</a></li>
    <li><a href="/air?s=3">Hang Gliding</a></li>
    <li><a href="/air?s=4">Base Jumping</a></li>
    <li><a href="/air?s=5">Balloons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Python

```
s = webapp2.request.get('s')
if s ==1:
    #do what I want with this one
elif s == 2:
    #same on down the line
```

Comment: No, it's wrong, why do you have several elements with the same name? and you should read about hidden elements and anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you insist using POST? If you worry about SEO posting forms is actually will lower the SEO quality of target pages. You can pass arguments as query string to server side with a get request. You won't need to post a form and you can still grab passed variables in target script and use them. For examples by calling `http://stackoverflow.com/posts?foo=bar&baz=qux` you could pass 2 variables to server side. In the handling script you can read:

```
foo = bar
baz = qux
```

If you still insist making a POST request, you should handle this with javascript. Try searching for "javascript form post"

Comment: I don't need to use POST i just didn't know you can pass arguments with a hyperlink without it.  what would that look like?

Comment: Edited question and added some query string examples.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript to accomplish this. I would also restructure some things. Here's the final solution I think you're looking for (using jQuery):

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form > li > a").click(function () { $(this).parent().parent().submit(); });
});
```

## HTML

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="/air/skydiving">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar1" />
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Skydiving</a></li>
</form>

<form name="myForm2" method="POST" action="/air/paragliding">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar2" />
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Paragliding</a></li>
</form>

<form name="myForm3" method="POST" action="/air/hanggliding">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar3" />
    <li><a href="javascript:;">hang gliding</a></li>
</form>

<form name="myForm4" method="POST" action="/air/basejumping">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar3" />
    <li><a href="javascript:;">base jumping</a></li>
</form>
```

Comment: No, I change my mind. This is what you said you want, but not what you actually want. The others are right, use GET variables for better SEO. Bonus points: use routing to make even "prettier" URLs